# Hyper-v Export-VM : Provider load failure error in 2012r2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I'm using powershell 4 to export all the VMs in hyper-V and move it to a backup server(nas unix). Export was successful for few VMs and after a while it fails with the following errors:

> Export-VM : Provider load failure
>
> At C:\scripts\test.ps1:37 char:5
>
> - Export-VM -Name $vmname -Path  $ExportPath
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-VM], ManagementException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.ExportVMCommand

This is the error i get in event viewer:

The description for Event ID 18350 from source Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

71706037-090D-4B74-BB0B-AEE96D47D898
%%2147942432
0x80070020

The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present

The same script works fine in windows 2016 server running powershell 5. I'm not sure if this is OS specific or it has to do with any updates. Please share your view on this and help me resolve this issue.

> Update

I also get this Error:

Get-VM : Quota violation 
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-VM
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-VM], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVMCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred because Hyper-V service became unresponsive. Restarting Windows Management Instrumentation service or hyper-v service fixed this issue.